# DatePicker Issue in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I am working on a PHP page where I need a date picker. So I added the following files:

```
<script src="../J/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="../J/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="../J/jquery-1.5.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="../J/jquery.ui.core.js"></script>
<script src="../J/jquery.ui.datepicker.js"></script>
```

Here's the relevant JS:

```
$(function() {
   $( "#Date" ).datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd-M-yy',
      showOn: "button",
      buttonImage: "../I/dateimg.png",
      minDate:'<?php echo $minDate; ?>',
      maxDate:'<?php echo $maxDate; ?>',
      buttonImageOnly: true,
      firstDay:1,
      beforeShowDay: checkDisabled,
      changeMonth: true,
      changeYear: true,
      beforeShow: function(input, inst){
         inst.dpDiv.css({marginTop: -input.offsetHeight + 'px', marginLeft:`input.offsetWidth-210 + 'px'});
      } 

   });
});
```

And here's the tag I'm using:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="Event_Date"  value="<?php echo $Todaysdate ?>" />
```

But still i am getting this below error

> TypeError: $(...).datepicker is not a function

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You use 3 different jquery version, why?

Comment: @RadonirinaMaminiaina it is easy to do such things when you don't understand what you do.

Comment: But he can use the latest jquery function or the `#Date` doesn't match in your file, I think, instead of using it, use `#Event_Date` id

Comment: where is the element with id `#Date` in your html ?

Answer (score 0):

Just remove these file because, there's maybe a regression between these jQuery version.

```
<script src="../J/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="../J/jquery-1.5.2.min.js"></script>
```

And use `$('#Event_Date').datepicker(opts)`, not `$('#Date').datepicker(opts)`.

And retest your code! :)

Comment: No sir! I have tried it already still its giving the same error

Answer (score 0):

put `$( "#Date" ).datepicker({...});` in `$( document ).ready()`

Comment: While this code may answer the question, a few words of explanation will help current and future readers understand this answer even better.

Comment: well @TheThom : its already inside `.ready()`. `$(function() {` is a shortcut of  `$( document ).ready()`, so thats not the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Actually `Jquery.ui.core.js` library doesn't support `datepicker()`,

Ref: http://jqueryui.com/download/

you need to refer to respective jquery.Ui.js library.

Check this example (it's the same code posted by OP without any php related tags).

**JS Code:**

```
$(function() {
$("#Date").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd-M-yy',
    showOn: "button",
    buttonImage: "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f0/Pixelart-tv-iso.png",
    minDate: '',
    maxDate: '',
    buttonImageOnly: true,
    firstDay: 1,
    beforeShowDay:'',
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    beforeShow: function(input, inst)
    {
        inst.dpDiv.css({ marginTop: -input.offsetHeight + 'px', marginLeft: input.offsetWidth-210 + 'px' });
    }
});
});
```

**Live Demo @ JSFiddle:**

http://jsfiddle.net/dreamweiver/7azwn7uj/4/

One more suggestion, always stick to latest libraries as it would be more stable.